# StackMob Custom Code Update Schema on Get Request

Tags: java, schema, stackmob, custom-code

I am trying to complete the StackMob hello_world tutorial for custom code found here:
https://www.stackmob.com/devcenter/docs/Getting-Started:-Custom-Code-SDK#a-register_your_method

but when I try to run the client-side iOS code it says:

```
{NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion={"error":"hello_world is not an existing schema"},
```

I tried to do a POST request to ReadParams from their example project and that created the schema and returned correctly. Maybe GET requests don't modify schemas, but then how do they expect you to do the hello_world example?

Thanks!

[EDIT]: I got this working by making sure the package is of the correct java package form with src directory, etc. Then I changed my package name and forgot to change the pom.xml file to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the API doesn't think there is a custom code method registered with that name yet. When you go to the settings page for the custom code module, you should see a list of the custom code methods available in the JAR which you uploaded.

If you don't see any such methods, then it is likely something went wrong trying to validate the JAR you uploaded. Feel free to contact support@stackmob.com with any questions specific to your app's custom code!

(Disclaimer: I'm a StackMob engineer)

Comment: I got this working from help on the stackmob support page for my question. Thanks.